# UPDATEing both referenced and referencing columns in a foreign key relationship

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have the following test case:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS test CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA test;

CREATE TABLE test.quz (
  foo int,
  bar int,
  PRIMARY KEY ( foo, bar )
);
CREATE TABLE test.quuz (
  foo int,
  bar int,
  baz int,
  PRIMARY KEY ( foo, bar ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( foo, bar ) REFERENCES test.quz MATCH FULL
);

INSERT INTO test.quz VALUES ( 1, 2 );
INSERT INTO test.quuz VALUES ( 1, 2, 3 );
```

However, even when `deferred` this doesn't seem to work.

```
BEGIN;
  SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
  UPDATE test.quz SET bar = 100 where bar = 2;
  UPDATE test.quuz SET bar = 100 where bar = 2;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Is there any reason? Can this task be done without the terseness of manually deleteing and re-inserting rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFERRABLE` means that constraints are checked at the end of each statement. `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, means that constraints are checked at the end of the transaction.

This should work in your case:

```
CREATE TABLE test.quuz (
  foo int,
  bar int,
  baz int,
  PRIMARY KEY ( foo, bar ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( foo, bar ) REFERENCES test.quz MATCH FULL DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

...

BEGIN;
  UPDATE test.quz SET bar = 100 where bar = 2;
  UPDATE test.quuz SET bar = 100 where bar = 2;
COMMIT;
```

This will probably work too:

```
CREATE TABLE test.quuz (
  foo int,
  bar int,
  baz int,
  PRIMARY KEY ( foo, bar ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( foo, bar ) REFERENCES test.quz MATCH FULL DEFERRABLE
);

...

BEGIN;
  SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
  UPDATE test.quz SET bar = 100 where bar = 2;
  UPDATE test.quuz SET bar = 100 where bar = 2;
COMMIT;
```

Unless I am mistaking, the issue in your definitions is that you don't mark your constraints as deferrable. So Postgres treats them as `NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` (i.e. the default in Postgres in spite of the SQL standard, the rational being that it is fastest) irrespective of `SET CONSTRAINTS` (which only affects deferrable constraints).

Comment: This is a great answer. That's confusing from my UI perspective. A better error is certainly called for.

Comment: Btw... depending on what you're doing, you might also want to look into: `REFERENCES test.quz MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE`.